# How can I get rid of the default large space between <li> in outlook? HTML Email Template

Tags: html, email, outlook, email-templates

I have an unordered list in an email template. On outlook there is a ridiculously large space between each list item. I've tried several methods - defining the space in tr and td between each item, using capital M for margin to set margin to 0 on outlook.

```
         <table>
              <tr>
                <td valign="middle" width="100%" style="text-align: center; font-family: Georgia, serif, 'Cormorant'; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; letter-spacing: .02em; color: #111111; font-weight: 300; font-style: italic;">
                  <ul style="list-style-position: inside; padding-left: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 0; Margin: 0;">
                    <li style="font-style: italic; Margin: 0;">Lorem Ipsum</li>

                    <li style="font-style: italic; Margin: 0;">Lorem Ipsum</li>

                    <li style="font-style: italic Margin: 0;;" >Transport - 450m (6 min walk)</li>

                    <li style="font-style: italic; Margin: 0;"> Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  </ul>
              </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: For one, you should only have `<li>` as children of `<ul>` - I see you have `<table>` elements - so that structure is invalid; but the space may be coming from the `<table>`s. I also see you have a `</multiline>` closing tag - I don't see a matching opening tag, and that's not a valid html tag to begin with.

Comment: Ive added these in to try and define a space as space was too large without them so I thought I could hack around it. Multiline opening tag is higher in the code as well as the table tags, will edit on post, thank you for pointing that out for me

Comment: You could also try leaving off the closing `</li>` tags - as long as you have only `<li>`s as children of the `<ul>`, this is legal, and does get rid of some white space.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work either

Comment: You must have something else going on - do you have any additional CSS somewhere in your html template? If I create a basic html document ([exactly this](https://jsfiddle.net/o4d6h9o4/2/)), and in Outlook 2016 I create a new message and click Attach File, and select Insert As Text, it looks fine to me - [here's a screenshot](https://snag.gy/wSvkpN.jpg).

Comment: Try table instead of ordered list. Tables haven't failed me yet.

Comment: Hey Jessica, Did my method do the trick for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would resort to tables for bullets. Its a little messy but we have total control over the look and feel.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="30" align="center" valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';font-size:12px;padding-bottom:10px;">&bull;</td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';font-size:12px;padding-bottom:10px;">First line of bullet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';font-size:12px;padding-bottom:10px;">&bull;</td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';font-size:12px;padding-bottom:10px;">Second line of bullet</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The table is set to 100% so it will take up the width of the parent td when placed in. Let me know if this works for you.