# How to align the second line in HTML Bullet point list

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

My Second bullet point "WiFi-enabled capabilities across the entire collection" shows up unaligned on **Outlook email**. The second line start with "entire" but it is indented to the right and not aligned exactly under the bullet point. How can I fix this?

```html
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 12%; padding: 0px;" class="hide_on_mobile">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 66.1667%; text-align: center; padding: 0px 10px 15px;" class="adonmobile2">
<ul>
<li style="color: #090a0a; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;">Premium-grade stainless-steel interiors</span></li>
<li style="color: #090a0a; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;">WiFi-enabled capabilities across the entire collection</span></li>
<li style="color: #090a0a; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;">Award-winning theater-style lighting</span></li>
<li style="color: #090a0a; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;">Thermador exclusive Diamond Ice</span></li>
<li style="color: #090a0a; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;">Intuitive Push-to-Open doors</span></li>
</ul>
</td>
<td style="width: 18.8333%; padding: 0px;" class="hide_on_mobile">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I would resort to tables. it gives you more control. Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641995/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-default-large-space-between-li-in-outlook-html-email/49642893#49642893

Answer (score 0):

4 steps that worked for me:

1. Open notepad or textEdit and paste your HTML code
2. Save your file as **outlook.html** (although you can use any name, you MUST use the .html extension)
3. Open the file in your prefered browser
4. copy all the content and paste it in your email

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the defaults (margins, paddings), and also use 'text-indent' for Outlook, noting that you should only use margin-left on the `<li>` element. If you want, you can also add top and bottom margins to the `<li>` (but don't use padding at all - it won't be consistent across email environments).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style>
li {
    text-indent:-1em;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
    </head>
<body>
<table width="400">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 12%; padding: 0px;" class="hide_on_mobile">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 66.1667%; text-align: center; padding: 0px 10px 15px;" class="adonmobile2">
<ul  style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<li style="color: #090a0a; margin:0 0 0 30px;padding:0; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;">Premium-grade stainless-steel interiors</span></li>
<li style="color: #090a0a; margin:0 0 0 30px;padding:0; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;">WiFi-enabled capabilities across the entire collection</span></li>
<li style="color: #090a0a; margin:0 0 0 30px;padding:0; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;">Award-winning theater-style lighting</span></li>
<li style="color: #090a0a; margin:0 0 0 30px;padding:0; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;">Thermador exclusive Diamond Ice</span></li>
<li style="color: #090a0a; margin:0 0 0 30px;padding:0; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;">Intuitive Push-to-Open doors</span></li>
</ul>
</td>
<td style="width: 18.8333%; padding: 0px;" class="hide_on_mobile">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Aligned bullet points]